# nesting synchron and asynchron spring webclient requests without block()

Tags: java, spring, webclient, reactive

i wrote a little piece of code as PoC to see if i can get that running. it should be a client for a website (oldschool chat system). unfortunately, they have some "special" handling of their website, e.g. frames and some calculations in .js that must be done before i can access the stream.

```
public void run() {

    final URI chatStreamUri = getUserStreamUrl();

    String block = webClient
            .get()
            .uri(chatStreamUri)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .map(s -> transformToBlah(s, chatAppUser.getInternalPass()))
            .flatMap(s -> webClient.get().uri(s).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class))
            .map(this::getCrapStreamUrl)
            .block();

    System.out.println("block url: " + block);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    webClient
            .get()
            .uri(block)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(String.class)
            .subscribe(writeTo,
            new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
                    System.out.println(throwable);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

unfortunately that throws the error in the sysout(throwable):
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-epoll-2

I only have the .block() in the synchronous part so i assume it is because of that.
the steps that must happen are:

- make a GET on the streamUrl (i guess that sets some cookies or so).
  that response contains some wierdo looking url like http://example.com/user/+pass+/stream, where i replace that +pass+ with the password of that user
- make a GET on the http://example.com/user/$verySecret/stream url to get the token - that is somehow generated on server side, so the response looks like: "the stream url is: [http://example.com/user/24987624/blabla/stream"](http://example.com/user/24987624/blabla/stream%22)
- and then listen on that http://example.com/user/24987624/blabla/stream for content

all those calls must be done on the same client object, i dont know why but when i access the stream url directly, it will fail (guess some cookie stuff).
anyone an idea how to achieve that with springs reactive webclient? or should i consider something else? maybe its not the correct library to use. thought i take a look at that fancy new reactive stuff ;)

btw.: when i debug, it works. thats why i added that ugly Thread.sleep() which unfortunately did not workaround the problem.

edit:

when i try it with this (as suggested i guess) it does not work:

```
 webClient
        .get()
        .uri(chatStreamUri)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(String.class)
        .map(s -> transformToBlah(s, chatAppUser.getInternalPass()))
        .flatMap(s -> webClient.get().uri(s).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class))
        .map(this::getCrapStreamUrl)
        .subscribe(writeTo, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println(throwable);
            }
        });
```

then i only receive a message like:
java.lang.RuntimeException: got  but cant work with that

this is from one of my methods that expect not a <html> but a text block containing way more text (like a window.replace code snippet -> thats where i filter out the next url i have to access).
when i debug that and set a breakpoint, i really only retrieve a <html> tag, nothing more

edit #2: when i use bodyToMono instead i get more stuff (makes sense now when i think about it), but still, the methods are not called as expected. Now the first method is called (transformToBlah()), then the second method is called which extracts the stream url, but then there is no subscribe on that extracted stream url, what happens is that the subscriber retrieves the stream url. thats not what i expected. for me, it looks like i have to now somehow call again webclient.get().uri($theResultFromMapThis::getCrapStreamUrl).subscribe(writeTo);

what does also not work is something like:

```
         webClient
            .get()
            .uri(chatStreamUri)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .map(s -> transformToBlah(s, chatAppUser.getInternalPass()))
            .flatMap(s -> webClient.get().uri(s).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class))
            .map(this::getCrapStreamUrl)
             .flatMap(s -> webClient.get().uri(s).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class))

            .subscribe(writeTo, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
                    System.out.println(throwable);
                }
            });
```

edit #3: what a heck of a ride. here is the code that works (a while):

```
        webClient
            .get()
            .uri(chatStreamUri)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .flatMap(s -> Mono.just(transformToBlah(s, chatAppUser.getInternalPass())))
            .flatMap(x -> webClient.get().uri(x).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class))
            .map(this::getCrapStreamUrl)
            .flatMapMany(s -> webClient.get().uri(s).retrieve().bodyToFlux(String.class))
            .subscribe(writeTo, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
                    System.out.println("err: " + throwable);
                }
            });
```

edit #4: i first thought the above code made it, and it works for some time, but then i again retrieve:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-epoll-2 from the System.out.println and no idea why :/

edit #5: seems like those exceptions are from a very different call, that has nothing to do with that part at all. i will open another thread for that. commented that other part/code and this works now as expected for about an hour, so guess the code works. thanks!
i will watch that application now for a couple of hours and if it still does work i close this.

Comment: Why would you need the block? Combine the 2 blocks you have now and it should it work. You could even add a delay in there if needs.

Comment: how should/can i combine them? i am fairly new to that reactive programming (and streams resp. this kind of api in general)

Comment: You are already doing that in the previous one, just continue the chain. Use a map or subscribe so that after retrieving the URL that will be called.

Comment: updated my initial post again, maybe you can answer how i can call the webclient now with the result from the map(::getCrapStreamUrl()) so that i can subscribe to that